# Combobox does not showing added items (with if condition)

Tags: c#

I have a question regarding combobox. Add first I try to add some items to classTimeComboBox by looping the array and it works. But when I try to combine the foreach looping with if condition and the combobox display nothing inside it. Can someone fix this for me?

[Here is my database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfRqu.png)
(All table in the database is in "Short Text" type.)

```
private void classTimeComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ClassTime = classTimeComboBox.Text;
    string ClassDate = classDateBox.Text;
    string[] ClassName = { "CL01", "CL02", "CL03", "CL04", "CL05", "CL06", "CL07", "CL08", "CL09" };

    if(classTimeComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "08:00")
    {
        foreach (string x in ClassName)
        {
            cnnOleDB.Open();
            checkAvailableClassRoom.CommandText = "Select * from Uploads where [ClassDate]='" + ClassDate + "' AND [ClassTime]='" + ClassTime + "' AND [ClassName]='" + x + "';";
            checkAvailableClassRoom.Connection = cnnOleDB;
            OleDbDataReader readDatabase = checkAvailableClassRoom.ExecuteReader();
            if (readDatabase.Read() != true)
            {
                classNameComboBox.Items.Add(x);
            }
            else
            {

            }
            cnnOleDB.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you debug? Specifically, is your query returning a result?

Comment: @John there is no error message at all

Comment: `if (readDatabase.Read() != true)` if satisfied then only item will be added to combobox, You need to debug your code and find the reason. No one can help on the logic you are trying to put unless you state. We also don't know what are the content of table **Uploads**.

Answer (score 0):

The `OleDbReader.Read()` advances the reader to the next record and the method returns

> true if there are more rows; otherwise, false.

So you should change the code, if you expect to have db more than one row, to this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    var stringIdx = reader.GetOrdinal("<string Colum to display in combobox>");
    classNameComboBox.Items.Add(reader.GetString(stringIdx));
}
```

If you only expect one row, or don't care about the number of rows you can change the `while` with the `if` you have with a small change:

```
if (readDatabase.Read() == true)
{
    classNameComboBox.Items.Add(x);
}
```

Comment: I'm using =! because I want to add "x" to the combobox if it does not exist in the database